# stable installed - (error reading rustc version)

Tags: linux, shell, rustup

I have trouble running rust in my linux box.

Here is my installation log:

```
>> curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh
info: downloading installer

Welcome to Rust!

This will download and install the official compiler for the Rust programming 
language, and its package manager, Cargo.

It will add the cargo, rustc, rustup and other commands to Cargo's bin 
directory, located at:

  /home/linuxbox/.cargo/bin

This path will then be added to your PATH environment variable by modifying the
profile files located at:

  /home/linuxbox/.profile
  /home/linuxbox/.bash_profile

You can uninstall at any time with rustup self uninstall and these changes will
be reverted.

Current installation options:

   default host triple: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
     default toolchain: stable
  modify PATH variable: yes

1) Proceed with installation (default)
2) Customize installation
3) Cancel installation
>1

info: syncing channel updates for 'stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
info: latest update on 2019-01-17, rust version 1.32.0 (9fda7c223 2019-01-16)
info: downloading component 'rustc'
 79.5 MiB /  79.5 MiB (100 %) 883.2 KiB/s ETA:   0 s                
info: downloading component 'rust-std'
 54.3 MiB /  54.3 MiB (100 %) 611.2 KiB/s ETA:   0 s                
info: downloading component 'cargo'
  4.4 MiB /   4.4 MiB (100 %) 761.4 KiB/s ETA:   0 s                
info: downloading component 'rust-docs'
  8.5 MiB /   8.5 MiB (100 %) 553.6 KiB/s ETA:   0 s                
info: installing component 'rustc'
info: installing component 'rust-std'
info: installing component 'cargo'
info: installing component 'rust-docs'
info: default toolchain set to 'stable'

  stable installed - (error reading rustc version)


Rust is installed now. Great!

To get started you need Cargo's bin directory ($HOME/.cargo/bin) in your PATH 
environment variable. Next time you log in this will be done automatically.
```

To configure your current shell run source $HOME/.cargo/env

I have set the the environment variable and my path shows the `/home/linuxbox/.cargo/bin/cargo`. However, when I type 'cargo` I am getting

```
>> cargo
bash: /home/linuxbox/.cargo/bin/cargo: Permission denied
```

`.cargo` and `.rustup` directory permissions are:

```
>> ll .cargo/ .rustup/
.cargo/:
total 16K
4.0K drwxr-xr-x  3 linuxbox linuxbox 4.0K Jan 20 10:13 ./
4.0K drwxr-xr-x 27 linuxbox linuxbox 4.0K Jan 20 10:08 ../
4.0K drwxr-xr-x  2 linuxbox linuxbox 4.0K Jan 20 10:08 bin/
4.0K -rw-r--r--  1 linuxbox linuxbox   37 Jan 20 10:13 env

.rustup/:
total 28K
4.0K drwxr-xr-x  6 linuxbox linuxbox 4.0K Jan 20 10:12 ./
4.0K drwxr-xr-x 27 linuxbox linuxbox 4.0K Jan 20 10:08 ../
4.0K drwxr-xr-x  2 linuxbox linuxbox 4.0K Jan 20 10:13 downloads/
4.0K -rw-r--r--  1 linuxbox linuxbox  124 Jan 20 10:13 settings.toml
4.0K drwxr-xr-x  2 linuxbox linuxbox 4.0K Jan 20 10:13 tmp/
4.0K drwxr-xr-x  3 linuxbox linuxbox 4.0K Jan 20 10:12 toolchains/
4.0K drwxr-xr-x  2 linuxbox linuxbox 4.0K Jan 20 10:13 update-hashes/
```

Permissions seem o.k but clueless why am I getting `Permission denied` error.

Could someone shed some light to help troubleshoot/fix this?

**EDIT**:

My distribution: Antix (Debian Based) and I am having a separate `/home` partition.

Comment: error say `/home/linuxbox/.cargo/bin/cargo` not `.cargo/` or `.rustup/`

Comment: what is a linux box ?

Comment: what is your distribution of linux ?

Comment: @Stargateur: It is deabian based distro `antiX`

Comment: @Stargateur. Sorry for the typo, edited the PATH variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to get that work by mounting my `/home` partition by adding the following line in the `/etc/fstab`

```
/dev/sda4            /home/rusty            ext4            defaults            0  2
```

Thank you guys